# What does "ерейшее иго восстанем" mean?

Tags: перевод

"восстанем" looks like "установим".

Comment: What's the context? Where did you see or hear this expression?

Comment: https://tenona.ru/putty/perevod-na-cerkovnoslavyanskii-yazyk-russkii-cerkovnoslavyanskii-slovar/

Comment: Да, восстановим власть священную (священник -иерей)

Answer (score 1):

Возста́вити - восстановить; поставить на прежнее место. (Церковнославянский)

Источник материала: https://tenona.ru/putty/perevod-na-cerkovnoslavyanskii-yazyk-russkii-cerkovnoslavyanskii-slovar/

Восстановим власть священную.